# Can I search in my question?

Tags: support, search

I would like to retrieve answers to old questions. Is there any way to search "only" on the questions I posted?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. Use the following search query (Assuming 257022 is your User ID on SO):

```
user:257022 something
```

([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:257022+syntax))

You can also use the shortcut

```
user:me sql
```

([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:me+sql))

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search) page for all search tips concerning SOFU sites.